# Icon and text not side by side nav bar with blade

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Working on a twiiter bootstrap with laravel web application. The problem is that the icon and text is not side by side. I am very unsure what the problem is, so hopefully can someone help me. The img picture is 24x24. Like this:

It works here (JUST HTML, bootstrap), not blade code: http://jsfiddle.net/aFtQ9/2/

[image]

default.blade.php

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            {{-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Norges Idrettshøgskole</a> --}}
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class='{{ ($aktiv == 'hvertime') ? 'active' : '' }}'> <a class='home'>{{HTML::linkRoute('hvertime','Forside')}}</a> </li>
           <li class='{{ ($aktiv == 'hvertredjetime') ? 'active' : '' }}'> <a class='home'>{{HTML::linkRoute('hvertredjetime','Måling')}}</a> </li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'gjoremal'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('gjoremal','Daglige Oppgaver')}} </li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'dagvakt'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('dagvakt','Dagvakt')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'kveldsvakt'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('kveldsvakt','Kveldsvakt')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'kontrollcm'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('kontrollcm','Kontroll CM')}}</li>
            <li @if($aktiv == 'sok'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('sok','Søk')}}</li>  
              {{--  <li @if($aktiv == 'diagrammer'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('diagrammer','Diagrammer')}}</li>  --}} 
              {{--  <li @if($aktiv == 'rapport'){{ "class='active'" }}@endif>{{HTML::linkRoute('rapport','Rapport')}}</li>  --}} 

          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

main.css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:before,
.navbar-nav>li>a:before {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 top;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 29px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a.home:before,
.navbar-nav>li>a.home:before { background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/j2s9NKB.png'); }
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem , do you want icons to be sort horizontally ?

Comment: Your fiddle looks good in IE9+, latest Chrome and FF. What browser are you using?

Comment: My problem is that the text has to be next to the icon, as it looks in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Why not simply drop the image between in your `a` elements?